# What is the difference bewteen SWAP and Virtual mmeory in Linux

Tags: redhat

Why I am not seeing any SWAP usage in below scenario, even though the virtual memory is showing 20gig ?

Tasks: 186 total,   1 running, 185 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.2%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32880880k total, 17555744k used, 15325136k free,   300268k buffers
Swap: 16383996k total,        0k used, 16383996k free,  2287700k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND

10314 abcuser 20   0 20.3g 6.8g  25m S  0.7 21.8  23:47.38 java

25119 abcuser 20   0 20.3g 6.7g  25m S  0.3 21.4  23:38.25 java

```
  total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
```

Mem:                 31         16         14          0          0          2

-/+ buffers/cache:         14         17

Swap:           15          0         15

Total:          46         16         30

Regards
Sanjeev